How to get the shortest segment AB between 2 SDF (Signed distance field) in 3D?
Is there a method to find the shortest segment between 2 Signed distance field?
I know how to calculate this segment for a limited number of SDF like from sphere to sphere, from capsule to sphere, from tor to sphere, from tor to capsule, from box to sphere...
I need a general method to find the segment AB between 2 SDF.
This involves finding the collision point and penetration depth between 2 SDFs someone.
A general method to suggest to me that works between 2 any SDF 3D?
Thanks in advance!

You mean two points on the zero-level set of the SDFs?

If your surfaces could be parameterised and were differentiable, it might be a lot easier.

Yes the 2 points must be at level 0 of the SDF. I had the idea of ​​using the gradient descent but it doesn't work for concave SDFs. This solution is therefore not reliable and generalizable for all types of SDF.
